# plotting two different dataframes on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two different dataframes on the same plot. But it only shows the second one. I have two dataframes: `reconstructed` and `expected` with the same shape. I need to plot them based on indexes (`idx`). So first I need to partition them based on each index; that is done by `ts_rec = reconstructed.loc[idx]` and `ts_exp = expected.loc[idx]`. Then I should plot these two new dataframes. Each of them has 28 columns, so I have 28 subplots with layout=(7, 4). The problem is that it only shows the second (red) timeseries, but I need to have both of them to be able to compare their values. How can I fix this?

```
ts_rec = reconstructed.loc[idx]
ts_exp = expected.loc[idx]
x = np.arange(ts_rec.shape[0])
ts_rec.plot(
    x=x, subplots=True, layout=(7, 4), lw=2, legend=False, 
    figsize=(12, 10), sharey=True, color='green')
ts_exp.plot(
    x=x, subplots=True, layout=(7, 4), lw=2, legend=False, 
    figsize=(12, 10), sharey=True, color='red')
pyplot.title("Timeseries id = %d" % idx)
pyplot.xlim(xmin=0)
pyplot.show()
pyplot.savefig(config['dir'] + 'ts_' + str(idx) + '.pdf')
pyplot.clf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store the `ax` handle from the first plot and pass it as `ax` argument to the second plot:

```
plt_ax = ts_rec.plot(
    x=x, subplots=True, layout=(7, 4), lw=2, legend=False, 
    figsize=(12, 10), sharey=True, color='green')
ts_exp.plot(
    ax=plt_ax, x=x, subplots=True, layout=(7, 4), lw=2, legend=False, 
    figsize=(12, 10), sharey=True, color='red')
```